# Dyalog APL: How to filter an array like filter()

Tags: arrays, nested, filtering, apl, dyalog

I need to filter out from the array (namespaces) all values that do not fulfil the required condition: field 'status' = 'TRADING'

I use this variant

```
tmpSymbolsT←(data←⎕JSON(HttpCommand.Get'api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo').Data).symbols
tmpSymbols←{(⍵.status≡'TRADING')⌿⍵}⍨¨tmpSymbolsT
```

However, it returns every row in the wrapper, and I want clean rows

```
      tmpSymbols[1] ⍝ I have
┌─────────────────────────────────┐
│┌───────────────────────────────┐│
││ #.[JSON object].[JSON object] ││
│└───────────────────────────────┘│
└─────────────────────────────────┘


      tmpSymbolsT[1] ⍝ I need like this
#.[JSON object].[JSON object]
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you filter each (`¨`) object separately, rather than filtering the entire collection.

(By the way, you also have an unnecessary commute (`⍨`) which doesn't do anything in this context.)

So, you really want something along the lines of `tmpSymbols←{(⍵.status≡'TRADING')⌿⍵}tmpSymbolsT`
but now `⍵.status` is a vector (list) of statuses, which of course won't match (`≡`) the single status `'TRADING'`.  You have a few options for fixing this:

1. `⍵.status≡¨⊂'TRADING'` uses an explicit each and encloses (`⊂`) the single status so it is used for every comparison.
2. `'TRADING'∘≡¨⍵.status` binds (`∘`) the single status to the match function, thus deriving an "is trading" function, which is then applied to each status.
3. `⍵.status∊⊂'TRADING'` which encloses the single status and checks all the statuses for which ones are a member of (`∊`) the array of a single status.

Here is an example of code that does what you want:

```
      tmpSymbolsT←(data←⎕JSON(HttpCommand.Get'api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo').Data).symbols
      tmpSymbols←{(⍵.status∊⊂'TRADING')⌿⍵}tmpSymbolsT
      tmpSymbols[1]
#.[JSON object].[JSON object]
```

Comment: `⍵.status∊⊆'TRADING'` is the pattern I like because it means you can filter by multiple (OR) simply by appending more terms as character vectors:
`⍵.status∊⊆'TRADING' 'BREAK'`

Comment: @RikedyP Dangerous, though, because sooner or later, you might look for multiple numeric values, and it'll fail. Better use `{⊂⍣(''≡0/⍵)⊢⍵}` than `⊆`